# Manhwa where a girl transmigrates into a novel as the villainess and befriends the female lead

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for a manhwa where a girl transmigrates into a novel and is the villainess. She befriends the female lead and the female lead is like a saintess who has a disease and dies. She has three males suitors. One is obsessive and the others she didn't get along with. The villainess leaves the day of the funeral for female lead and opens a cafe. The male leads eventually find her. Also, the villainess has black hair.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

This is *[The Bad Ending of an Otome](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-bad-ending-of-an-otome)*.

> I was reincarnated into the otome game I had played in my previous life. Ophelia, a beautiful female protagonist like a goddess, is loved by numerous nobles while Emilia, the character I reincarnated as, has a supporting role of a villain and she follows around the male leads after Ophelia’s death, only to be destroyed by them. A few years after Ophelia dies due to an incurable disease, the player (default name Elodi) who resembles Ophelia appears. The male love targets, who were heartbroken from the loss of Ophelia, becomes obsessed with Elodi. I, who reincarnated into the story and became Emilia, decided to abandon that kind of plot. So, I decided to quietly leave the place I had lived at for 10 years on the day of Ophelia’s funeral. Nobody expected her to leave, and they were shocked...

[image: Cover]

The cover depicts the main character, the villainess, who has black hair.

The synopsis covers the reincarnation as a villainess, the saintess dying, and the main character leaving during the funeral.

She leaves and opens a cafe, and by coincidence is discovered by one of the original male leads. With him is the female lead, who looks the same as her deceased friend.