# Manhwa with a main character who's transported into a novel where the original female lead dies

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It starts off with the main character (MC) being transported into a novel where the original story's female lead (OG FL) dies and has about four suitors. After the OG FL dies, the four suitors find a replacement for the OG FL and fight to win her love. After the MC got isekaied, she becomes friends with the OG FL until she dies. At the OG FL's funeral, the four suitors call the MC out for not crying at the OG FL's funeral, and after she tells them off a little while later, she runs away to live life as a commoner.

She thought no one would care if she ran away, but surprisingly one of the guys who was in love with the OG FL finds the MC at her job and says that if she comes with him to a ball, he’ll give her a letter the OG FL left for her. She’s skeptical at first, but then accepts. The OG ML from the novel, instead of loving the OG FL, loves the MC and he has black hair. The MC didn't know, but all the four guys that loved the OG FL looked for her after she left.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

This is *[The Bad Ending of an Otome](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-bad-ending-of-an-otome)*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/264925/102326).

> I was reincarnated into the otome game I had played in my previous life. Ophelia, a beautiful female protagonist like a goddess, is loved by numerous nobles while Emilia, the character I reincarnated as, has a supporting role of a villain and she follows around the male leads after Ophelia’s death, only to be destroyed by them. A few years after **Ophelia dies due to an incurable disease, the player (default name Elodi) who resembles Ophelia appears. The male love targets, who were heartbroken from the loss of Ophelia, becomes obsessed with Elodi**. I, who reincarnated into the story and became Emilia, decided to abandon that kind of plot. So, I decided to quietly leave the place I had lived at for 10 years on the day of Ophelia’s funeral. Nobody expected her to leave, and they were shocked...

[image: Cover]

Ophelia dies in the first chapter, with her funeral taking place in the second. The main character doesn't cry, causing some of the others to comment on her being heartless, and one of Ophelia's suitors explicitly calls her out on this after the funeral.

[image: One of the suitors calling her heartless]

She leaves and opens a cafe, and by coincidence is discovered by one of the original male leads. With him is the female lead, who looks the same as her deceased friend.

Another of the suitors comes shortly after and tries to get her to attend a debutante ball with him as her escort. She refuses, until he mentions a letter he possesses from Ophelia, and uses this to force her to attend with him.

[image: Letter from the dead girl]