# Isekai webtoon where the female lead is reborn into the role of a side character

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

The main character (MC) is reborn into the role of a side character in a game/novel? This side character is the game/novel's female lead's best friend, who dies, and this is the beginning of the novel/game. The novel's female lead (FL) then goes to visit her late-best friend and from there she meets the male leads. When the MC meets the FL, something is off and it seems like the FL may be aware that she is in a game/novel.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of any of the main characters?

Comment: Also, what was the nature of the main character's death?

Comment: I will also note that the "become secondary character in the novel" is a *very* common manhua plot, so the more details you can give, the better. Is it a medieval setting? Renaissance? European? Korean? Was there magic other than the transmigration? Did the MC die before being transported, a reincarnation?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Can you expand on the characters and their roles? Is it the protagonist of the manga that dies? Or does she just know that she will die because she's familiar with the original work? If an important character actually dies, I'd suggest [The Bad Ending of an Otome](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264920), but I can't tell if that is what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

This could be [The Reason Why Raeliana Ended up at the Duke's Mansion](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-reason-why-raeliana-ended-up-at-the-dukes-mansion).

The story matches your description pretty well:

The main character is killed in the real world and wakes up as side character in a novel. In the novel, the character she is possessing is killed by her fiance and her death becomes the reason for the female lead (of the novel) to return to the city and subsequently meet the male lead while investigating her death.

The main character disturbs the story by entering a contracted engagement with the male lead, to break free from her fiance.

In the novel, the MC and the FL are friends, but the FL does not really act as her friend, and seems to be aware that the world has been altered.